# Ruby on Rails, displaying multiple attributes from multiple model instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Ruby on Rails project I have a Country model class and a Proposal model class.  Each Country has many Proposals and each Proposal belongs to a Country.  Each Proposal has 30 questions (attributes).  In my view page, I want to display each question for every proposal that a country has.

So far, I have:

```
<div class="relative"> 
   <% @country.proposals.each do |proposal| %> 
     <h2>Food and Medicine:</h2><br>
         <div class="relative2">
           <p>List of prohibited drugs:</p>
           <p><% proposal.q1 %></p>
         </div>
     <h2>Liquids and Gels:</h2><br>
         <div class="relative2">
           <p>List of prohibited liquids/gels:</p>
           <p><% proposal.q2 %></p>
           ...
      ...
   <% end %>
</div>
```

The headings appear fine whenever the country has a proposal associated with it.  However, the proposal attributes do not appear where I have placed them (in between the headings).  I can confirm the attributes are not empty.

Proposal table:

```
create_table "proposals", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "status",     default: "Pending"
  t.text     "q1"
  t.text     "q2"
  ...
  ...
  t.text     "q29"
  t.text     "q30"
  t.datetime "created_at",                     null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                     null: false
  t.integer  "country_id"
end
```

Comment: change this <p><% @proposals_q1 %></p>

Comment: `<%= @country.proposals.each do |proposals| %>` to `<% @country.proposals.each do |proposals| %>` and `<% @proposals_q1 %>` to `<%= @proposals_q1 %>`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot an equal sign. You should do:

```
<p><%= @proposals_q2 %></p>
```

Instead of:

```
<p><% @proposals_q2 %></p>
```

In addition you should remove the equal sign from your loop.

```
<% @country.proposals.each do |proposals| %>
```

Instead of:

```
<%= @country.proposals.each do |proposals| %>
```

In ERB, `<%= expression %>` is used to inject the evaluated expression into the DOM. `<% expression %>` is used to evaluate the expression and not do anything with it. You **don't** want the result of `@country.proposals.each {...}` to be evaluated on the first line and injected into the DOM, so you want it **without** the equal sign, while you **do** want each of the instance variables to be injected into the DOM, so you want them **with** the equal sign.

By the way, I assume that `@proposals_q1`, `@proposals_q2`, etc. are initialized in the controller action. If instead you have `q1`, `q2`, etc. as attributes on the `Proposal` model, then instead of using `@proposals_q1` you should do something like:

```
<div class="relative"> 
   <% @country.proposals.each do |proposal| %> 
     <h2>Food and Medicine:</h2><br>
         <div class="relative2">
           <p>List of prohibited drugs:</p>
           <p><%= proposal.q1 %></p>
         </div>
     <h2>Liquids and Gels:</h2><br>
         <div class="relative2">
           <p>List of prohibited liquids/gels:</p>
           <p><%= proposal.q2 %></p>
           ...
      ...
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: The attributes do not appear at the bottom anymore, however they still do not appear in between the headings as well

Comment: Do you have the `@proposals_q2` defined in the controller?

Comment: No. Does that mean I have to create a method for every attribute in the model?

Comment: No you don't. Just updated my answer for how you can call the model attributes in your view.

Comment: Sorry, for that I get the error "undefined method 'q1' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: This can only happen if you're doing something like `proposal.q1` and `proposal` is nil. Also (somewhat related) - can you show us how your `proposals` table look like? It should be in the file `db/schema.rb`

Comment: Berry, your proposals table looks good. Please double check your code to make sure it is exactly as I wrote it (no `@` or plural form instead of singular form)

Comment: Everything is the same, it still does not display the 'q1' through 'q30' attributes

Comment: OK, but you don't have an error anymore. That's progress! Can you make sure the `@country` you setup in the controller has `proposals` records and that some of them indeed have `qxxx` fields filled correctly and not empty? Easiest is from console do ` x = Country.find(<some_id>).proposals` and take a peek at the results. Like `x.first.q1`.

Comment: Ok great! Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `<%=` and `<%` backwards. `<%=` outputs stuff to the page. `<%` runs Ruby code but doesn't output anything.

As it stands, you are outputting the result of `<%= @country.proposals.each`, and you are *not* outputting the `<% @proposals_q1`. That means that, inside the loop, the line `<% @proposals_q1 %>` has absolutely no effect, but after the entire loop is done, `<%= @country.proposals.each...` outputs `proposals`.

You need to use `<%= @proposals_q1 %>` to output the contents of that variable, inside the markup being written inside your loop, and you need to use `<% @country.proposals.each... %>` because there is no useful output generated by that use of `<%=`.

Answer (score -1):

change this '

<% @proposals_q1 %>

"  to this: "

<%= @proposals_q1 %>

"